# jQuery hash attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

At 4 minutes into the "Scroll Linked Navigation" podcast Posted: Wed, 18 Aug 2010 at 
[jQuery for Designers](http://feeds.feedburner.com/jqueryfordesigners-podcast), Remy uses the hash attribute.

Q: Where is the hash attribute documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('a[hash=#foo]')` isn't explicitly documented, but it makes sense given the following:

A) The Link object has a [`hash` property](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/hash.html).

B) jQuery's "[attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)" works on properties (not just attributes).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

`hash` - The part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol.
You can listen for the `hashchange` event to get notified of changes to the hash in supporting browsers

Comment: The referenced section of the video isn't about `window.location`.